# JavaScript indexOf() Method giving -1 when decimal value is present in array

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble with the JavaScript indexOf() Method. I have an array...

```
      pointLatArray = new Array();
```

When I try to get the index of a variable that I know is present in the array it returns -1, which I know normally indicates to the value not being found. When my code is as follows..

```
      setlat = 52.6688391881732;
      pointArrayIndex = pointLatArray.indexOf(setlat);
      console.log(setlat + " " + pointLatArray[8] + " " + pointArrayIndex);
```

I get the following logged to console.....

```
       04-16 12:35:31.370: D/CordovaLog(7048): 52.6688391881732 52.6688391881732 -1
```

However when I change the code by replacing setlat with pointLatArray[8] in the following line....

```
      pointArrayIndex = pointLatArray.indexOf(pointLatArray[8]);
```

the following gets logged to console where it displays the correct index of 8 instead of -1 as expected.......

```
      04-16 12:46:17.230: D/CordovaLog(8497): 52.6688391881732 52.6688391881732 8
```

Is it because I'm using such a long decimal set as the variable setlat? If so, or for what ever reason if anyone could suggest a fix I would appreciate it very much.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strict comparison for double numbers is not a good idea. Probably what you observe here is rounding error. Although the numbers seem to be the same to you they may differ by a small epsylon.

One option I see is to use [custom indexOf function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356642/is-there-an-indexof-in-javascript-to-search-an-array-with-custom-compare-functio) using epsylon comparison(i.e. allow numbers to differ by a small value. For instance `0.000000000001` or `1e-12`).

Comment: Ok, cheers, so what would my alternative be as I'm trying to get the index of a latitude value within the array?

Comment: sorry I was just searching for the right link. Take a look at my last sentence.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at there now and see can I get something from it.