# find the array index of an object with a specific key value in underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In underscore, I can successfully find an item with a specific key value

```
var tv = [{id:1},{id:2}]
var voteID = 2;
var data = _.find(tv, function(voteItem){ return voteItem.id == voteID; });
//data = { id: 2 }
```

but how do I find what array index that object occurred at?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an indexOf in javascript to search an array with custom compare function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356642/is-there-an-indexof-in-javascript-to-search-an-array-with-custom-compare-functio)

Comment: Thanks - this is useful - but in the example listed you are searching for a single number in an array of numbers - I am looking for a key value in an array of objects. Will this function accommodate that?

Comment: Whether its a numeric test or your property equaility predicate does not matter, yes.

Comment: Try `findIndex`: `var dataIndex = _.findIndex(tv, { id: voteID })`

Comment: Please consider accepting [the answer that gives an Underscore solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26847450/2493235), as requested in the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't know if there is an existing underscore method that does this, but you can achieve the same result with plain javascript.

```
Array.prototype.getIndexBy = function (name, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i][name] == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Then you can just do:

`var data = tv[tv.getIndexBy("id", 2)]`

Comment: Why not a `return -1;` by default?

Answer (score 181):

`findIndex` was added in 1.8:

```
index = _.findIndex(tv, function(voteItem) { return voteItem.id == voteID })
```

See: http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex

Alternatively, this also works, if you don't mind making another temporary list:

```
index = _.indexOf(_.pluck(tv, 'id'), voteId);
```

See: http://underscorejs.org/#pluck

Comment: I'm not sure about underscore but in lodash you don't need an anonymous function, simply `index = _.findIndex(tv, {id: voteID})` will work, also works if the `tv` collection has more complicated values (more than just an `id` property)

Comment: Just a point using pluck is so much slower. I because of its extra traverse. https://jsperf.com/compare-find-index

Answer (score 44):

[Lo-Dash](https://lodash.com), which extends Underscore, has [findIndex](https://lodash.com/docs#findIndex) method, that can find the index of a given instance, or by a given predicate, or according to the properties of a given object.

In your case, I would do:

```
var index = _.findIndex(tv, { id: voteID });
```

Give it a try.

Comment: findIntex it'ts a method from lo-dash, not from underscore

Comment: @WallyssonNunes This is exactly what I wrote - "Lo-Dash, which extends Underscore, has findIndex method"

Comment: This is now part of the standard underscore library, as of version 1.8.0: http://underscorejs.org/#1.8.0

Answer (score 38):

If you want to stay with underscore so your predicate function can be more flexible, here are 2 ideas.

#### Method 1

Since the predicate for `_.find` receives both the value and index of an element, you can use side effect to retrieve the index, like this:

```
var idx;
_.find(tv, function(voteItem, voteIdx){ 
   if(voteItem.id == voteID){ idx = voteIdx; return true;}; 
});
```

#### Method 2

Looking at underscore source, this is how `_.find` is implemented:

```
_.find = _.detect = function(obj, predicate, context) {
  var result;
  any(obj, function(value, index, list) {
    if (predicate.call(context, value, index, list)) {
      result = value;
      return true;
    }
  });
  return result;
};
```

To make this a `findIndex` function, simply replace the line `result = value;` with `result = index;` This is the same idea as the first method. I included it to point out that underscore uses side effect to implement `_.find` as well.

Answer (score 13):

If your target environment supports ES2015 (or you have a transpile step, eg with Babel), you can use the native Array.prototype.findIndex().

Given your example

```
const array = [ {id:1}, {id:2} ]
const desiredId = 2;
const index = array.findIndex(obj => obj.id === desiredId);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `indexOf` method from `lodash`

```
var tv = [{id:1},{id:2}]
var voteID = 2;
var data = _.find(tv, function(voteItem){ return voteItem.id == voteID; });
var index=_.indexOf(tv,data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Keepin' it simple:

```
// Find the index of the first element in array
// meeting specified condition.
//
var findIndex = function(arr, cond) {
  var i, x;
  for (i in arr) {
    x = arr[i];
    if (cond(x)) return parseInt(i);
  }
};

var idIsTwo = function(x) { return x.id == 2 }
var tv = [ {id: 1}, {id: 2} ]
var i = findIndex(tv, idIsTwo) // 1
```

Or, for non-haters, the CoffeeScript variant:

```
findIndex = (arr, cond) ->
  for i, x of arr
    return parseInt(i) if cond(x)
```

Comment: better would be `return parseInt(i) for i, x of array when cond(x)`

Comment: how this is simple than previous answers??

Answer (score 2):

This is to help `lodash` users. check if your key is present by doing:

```
hideSelectedCompany(yourKey) {
 return _.findIndex(yourArray, n => n === yourKey) === -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use lodash:

1. Install lodash:

> npm install --save lodash

2. Use method findIndex:

const _ = require('lodash');

```
findIndexByElementKeyValue = (elementKeyValue) => {
  return _.findIndex(array, arrayItem => arrayItem.keyelementKeyValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting multiple matches and hence need an array to be returned, try:

```
_.where(Users, {age: 24})
```

If the property value is unique and you need the index of the match, try:

```
_.findWhere(Users, {_id: 10})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.getIndex = function (obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i][Id] == obj.Id) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

List.getIndex(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar case but in contrary is to find the used key based on index of a given object's. I could find solution in *underscore* using `Object.values` to returns object in to an array to get the occurred index.

```js
var tv = {id1:1,id2:2};
var voteIndex = 1;
console.log(_.findKey(tv, function(item) {
  return _.indexOf(Object.values(tv), item) == voteIndex;
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**And If you want some particular key value from an object by id then use**

```
var tv = [{id:1, name:"ABC"},{id:2, name:xyz}]

_.find(tv , {id:1}).value // retrun "ABC"
```

Comment: But how do I know the index of that result?