# I want to delete multiple rows selected from table, dom is changing but it is deleting rows from last on html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to delete multiple rows on check box selection on right click menu option, in my controller am able to get index and delete the values from DOM, but on html page the values are not getting deleted as per the selection rather it is deleting the rows from last.

This is my controller.js

```
$scope.tableSelection = {};//used for getting checkbox selection
  ['Delete', function ($itemScope) {
       for (var i = $rootScope.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           if ($scope.tableSelection[i]) {
             //delete row from data
             $rootScope.rows.splice(i, 1);
             //delete rowSelection property
             delete $scope.tableSelection[i];
           }
       }
 }];
```

here in controller the dom is changing correctly, means the values in `$rootscope.rows` is getting deleted as per the selection.

This is my html page.

```
<div id="table" context-menu="menuOptions" ng-controller="dictionaryElementsController">
  <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" ng-class="{'success' : tableSelection[$index]}">
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tableSelection[$index]">
       </td>
           <td  ng-repeat="col in output_columns track by $index">
         &lt;enter data&gt;
       </td>
       <td ng-repeat="col in input_columns track by $index">
         &lt;enter data&gt;
       </td>

        </tr>
   </tbody>
</div>
```

what should i do to delete the row as per selection and not rows from last on html page.
Can anyone please help me out in this

Comment: @ok, so I am somewhat confused on what you are trying to do. Do you want to remove rows from a table, is that it?

Comment: yes i want to remove the rows from table

Comment: Why don't you just use JavaScript!

Comment: I tried using javascript    var table= document.getElementsByTagName('table');
                                   table[0].childNodes[3].removeChild(table[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[i*2]);
                                   table[0].childNodes[3].removeChild(table[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[i*2]);  //added this line because two tags are created for one entry, one is of comment

Comment: is this the right approach. I did i*2 because i is taking index as per angular var $rootscope.rows and in html the values comes in pair of 2, 1 entry is for value and 1 for comment. But for zero index i have to put another check then

Comment: I personally tend to use JavaScript as much as I can. I don't like loading those large libraries for something so trivial!

Comment: `$rootScope.rows.splice(i, 1)` didn't work ? NO access DOM from controller is not right approach, you supposed to access DOM from `directive`.

Comment: $rootScope.row.splice(i,1) is working. It is deleting the rows as per selection. But on html page it is not deleting the rows which were selected. It is deleting the rows from last only

Comment: I tried your plunker but still it is deleting rows from last only, don't know what's going wrong

Comment: I am not sure but you may have a dirty scope. You are trying to delete a row in an array wtihc is located in rootScope. rootScope is a parent scope so your child may not aware that rootScope is changed.
Try to use
$scope.$apply()
or
$scope.$digest()

Answer (score 0):

As you can see it is very simple using vanilla javascript.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('sample');

var remove = document.getElementById('remove');

remove.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  table.deleteRow(0);
});
```

```html
<table id='sample'>
  <tr><td>Cell 1,1</td><td>Cell 1,2</td><td>Cell 1,3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell 2,1</td><td>Cell 2,2</td><td>Cell 2,3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell 3,3</td><td>Cell 3,3</td><td>Cell 3,3</td></tr>
</table>
<button id='remove'>Remove</button>
```

Comment: OP using angularjs why do you suggest plain javascript ? How does she fit this code with angular ?

Comment: I am not an expert on Angular but as far as I heard you can use it!

Comment: Is there any way in angular, through which i can remove rows from table.

Comment: Thank you @Reza and Gacci for your valuable help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove item inside `iteration for(..)` so after removing any item, array will be reset and next time wrong item will be removed. This will work only single item deletion **Not for mulitple**.

You need to create new array which contain **not removed items** you can do it  using `filter` like

```
$scope.removeSelectedItems = function () {
    $scope.rows = $scope.rows.filter(function (item, index) {
        return !($scope.tableSelection[index] !== undefined && $scope.tableSelection[index]);
    });
    $scope.tableSelection = {};
}
```

**Note** - Don't mess `$rootScope` because it is application level global use respective controller's `$scope`

Check the [**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/yQbxyXU3Z70fa8Fv8jQt?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The thing i was doing wrong was using track by.. If we don't use track by then angular itself keep track of objects and insert $$hashkey with every object. So, my logic worked after removing track by from ng-repeat in HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any unique column to the tableselection.
NOte: If you do not have unique column add one. Could be timespan

```
    <div id="table" context-menu="menuOptions" ng-controller="dictionaryElementsController">
  <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index" ng-class="{'success' : tableSelection[$index]}">
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tableSelection[row.Id]">
       </td>
           <td  ng-repeat="col in output_columns track by $index">
         &lt;enter data&gt;
       </td>
       <td ng-repeat="col in input_columns track by $index">
         &lt;enter data&gt;
       </td>

        </tr>
   </tbody>
</div>



 $scope.tableSelection = {};//used for getting checkbox selection
  ['Delete', function ($itemScope) {
       for (var i = $rootScope.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           if ($scope.tableSelection[$scope.row[i].UId]){
             //delete row from data
             $rootScope.rows.splice(i, 1);
             //delete rowSelection property
             delete $scope.tableSelection[i];
           }
       }
 }];
```