# How to change an array elements property

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

This is what I have. I am trying to update the firstName value in my selected array element. When I execute the code it just adds what I try to identify as the property and the desired value to the selected array element.

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var data = [
{id:1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'},
{id:2, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
{id:3, firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Smith'}
 ];

module.exports.lookupById = function(id, newName) {
console.log('Lookup By ID: ' +  (id));
Id = _.where(data, {id: id });
console.log(Id);    
newId = Id;
newId['firstName'] = newName;
console.log(newId);
```

This code is in a file that executes the above code

```
var foo = require('./hwa1');
foo.lookupById(2, 'Mary');
```

Comment: Is that Lodash or Underscore? What version?

Comment: Sorry for not putting that. It is underscore.

Comment: [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) doesn't return what you think it does, try [`_.find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find). Also, you have not declared `Id` or `newId` and `newId` is completely redundant

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631127/find-the-array-index-of-an-object-with-a-specific-key-value-in-underscore

Comment: @Darkrum doesn't look related. That question is about finding the index of the item

Comment: simple for loop is all that is needed. :) Library overkill.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That worked. I guess I need to look more into undersocre library.

Comment: @MatthewKing no, you should read the documentation for the libraries and methods you intend to use

Comment: @Phil yes it is read answer about findIndex

Comment: @Darkrum but OP doesn't want to find the index, they want to modify a property on the first element that matches the predicate.

Comment: findIndex would find it and return the index so then he could do data[i].firstName = "foo" but yes if he wants to return just the newId and not the data with the modified id then sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that with a regular loop, check the following code:

```
var data = [
    {id:1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'},
    {id:2, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
    {id:3, firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Smith'}
];

function lookupById(id, newName) {
    _.each(data, function(item) {
         if(item.id === id) {
             item.firstName = newName
         }
    });
}
```

This will change every item with id matches the criteria.

Or using findWhere which gives you a cleaner code:

```
function lookupById(id, newName) {
     var itemToChange = _.findWhere(data, { id: id });
     itemToChange.firstName = newName;
 }
```

This will only change the first item where the id matches your criteria.