# How to get particular object after compare particular key _id.$iod in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I am using mongoDB for storing the data and retrieving the data. So I am getting response data. I can get particular object from comparing name,But when I want to compare _id.$oid then it is giving me undefined. I am sharing my code.

```
   Array.prototype.getIndexBy = function (name, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i][name] == value) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    var data = documents[documents.getIndexBy("_id.$oid", "33453223")]
    console.log("----------updates-------->",data);
```

**SAMPLE JSON**

```
[
{"_id":{"$oid":"3426"},
"name":"peeter"
},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5a027"},
"name":"ken"
},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5999"},
"name":"karmal"
}
]
```

I am able to compare with name, But I want to compare with _id.$oid, When I am taking _id.$oid then It is giving me undefined value. I want to compare only with _id. I am referring link
[find the array index of an object with a specific key value in underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631127/find-the-array-index-of-an-object-with-a-specific-key-value-in-underscore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using lodash/underscore.js, you can use [`_.find`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find)

```js
var users = [
  {"_id":{"$oid":"3426"},
  "name":"peeter"
  },
  {"_id":{"$oid":"5a027"},
  "name":"ken"
  },
  {"_id":{"$oid":"5999"},
  "name":"karmal"
  }
];
 
var index = _.find(users, function(o) { return o._id.$oid == '5999'; });

console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment.  But I want to get object like [{"_id":{"$oid":"5999"},
  "name":"karmal"
  }]

Comment: I thought, you only want the index value. I'll change my code

Comment: can we add copy with name. mean change key name. example. copy_karmal...with existing code

Comment: we can. using above code, you are getting the required object. Change the name propperty in that and add it to the array

Comment: How can I delete particular key?

Comment: What you mean by key? You wanna delete that object?

Comment: Yes I want to delete o._id.$oid after comparing

Comment: use _.remove function in the same way as above. It'll remove the matching object

Comment: Thanks, But I want to delete only key _id.$oid. Not a object.

Comment: using `delete obj._id` and push the object into array