# Return array index where sub value is max with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have a setup like this:

```
docs[0]['edits'] = 1;
docs[1]['edits'] = 2;
```

I want to get the `docs[index]` of the one with the most edits.

Using Underscore I can get the appropriate array (ie the value `docs[1]`), but I still don't know the actual index in relation to `docs`.

```
_.max(docs, function(doc) { return doc['edits']; });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is using underscore *required*? This is very easy without a library

Comment: @CertainPerformance No, but I'm using Underscore elsewhere and it's nice to get the most out of the library. How would you suggest without Underscore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find the array index of an object with a specific key value in underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631127/find-the-array-index-of-an-object-with-a-specific-key-value-in-underscore)

Comment: Agreed with @CertainPerformance this is pretty trivial in JS using [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). Underscore is ideally meant to compliment normal JS by doing things it doesn't. This is something plain JS can do just fine. Or you can do other options to do the find and index find in one loop instead of two.

Comment: :-) Fair enough. I just loved the elegance of underscore. Will give @CertainPerformance's code below a go though.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output? It's not clear at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

To do it without a library, iterate over the array (possibly with `reduce`), storing the highest number so far and the highest index so far in a variable, reassigning both when the item being iterated over is higher:

```js
const edits = [
  3,
  4,
  5,
  0,
  0
];

let highestNum = edits[0];
const highestIndex = edits.reduce((highestIndexSoFar, num, i) => {
  if (num > highestNum) {
    highestNum = num;
    return i;
  }
  return highestIndexSoFar;
}, 0);

console.log(highestIndex);
```

Another way, with `findIndex`, and spreading the `edits` into `Math.max` (less code, but requires iterating twice):

```js
const edits = [
  3,
  4,
  5,
  0,
  0
];
const highest = Math.max(...edits);
const highestIndex = edits.indexOf(highest);

console.log(highestIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `maxBy`

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const docs = [{'edits': 1}, {'edits': 2}, {'edits': 0}, {'edits': 4}, {'edits': 3}]

const result = _.maxBy(docs, a => a.edits)

console.log(result)
```

https://repl.it/@NickMasters/DigitalUtterTechnologies

Pure JS way

```
const result2 = docs.reduce((result, { edits }) => edits > result ? edits : result, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER)

console.log(result2)
```