# indexOf () in IE 8 and _.indexOf() of underscore.js library - avoid case sensitivness

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, indexof

I was using indexOf method on top of an array in IE 8 and it gave error (as it is not suported). I opted to use underscore.js library. I used the `_.indexOf(array, value, [isSorted])` from underscorejs library. But indexOf() of underscore.js library is case sensitive but I want to ignore the case while comparing the value. How can I ignore case while using this function.

**I can always use for loop to loop over the array and then use toLowerCase() but I wonder if there is out of box method which can do this for me.**

Comment: indexOf is always case sensitive, but you can use a regex with the i flag to get case insensitive matches.

Comment: @Teemu: That's just what he said in the first sentence???

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make the string to lower case and then check the index of lower cased string.

Like:

```
"Hi I am string".toLowerCase().indexOf("Hi".toLowerCase());
```

Comment: OP is asking for Array `indexOf`!

Comment: @Bergi, but he is talking about case sensitiveness!!

Comment: Yes, a case insensitive matching instead of the `===` that Array::indexOf performs!

Answer (score 1):

> I can always use for loop to loop over the array and then use toLowerCase()

That's basically the way to go.

> but I wonder if there is out of box method which can do this for me.

No, yet you don't have to use a for-loop if you use [this `indexOf` variant with an iterator callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12356642/1048572).

Since I don't know what you do need the index for, maybe [`_.find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) or [`_.some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some) do work as well for you.