# Generic implementation of _.indexOf

Tags: typescript

I am trying to port the implementation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356642/is-there-an-indexof-in-javascript-to-search-an-array-with-custom-compare-functio) to typescript
This works, but I like to make it as a generic fn, along with others in the [lodash _.indexOf implementation](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/lodash/lodash.d.ts).

```
indexOf<T>(
            array: Array<T>,
            value: T): number;

        /**
        * @see _.indexOf
        **/
        indexOf<T>(
            array: List<T>,
            value: T): number;

etc...
```

I using it like this now

```
var idx = _.indexOf(myList, (r:Type) => {
      return r.Name == k;
});
```

I am looking for a way to use the below implementation like

```
var idx = _.indexOf<Type>(myList, (r) => {
      return r.Name == k;
});
```

untyped implementation:

```
var indexOfValue = _.indexOf;

// using .mixin allows both wrapped and unwrapped calls:
// _(array).indexOf(...) and _.indexOf(array, ...)
_.mixin({

    // return the index of the first array element passing a test
    indexOf: (array:_.List<any>, test:Function):any => {
        // delegate to standard indexOf if the test isn't a function
        if (!_.isFunction(test)) return indexOfValue(array, test);
        // otherwise, look for the index
        for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            if (test(array[x])) return x;
        }
        // not found, return fail value
        return -1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote a while back :

```
export function indexOf<T>(items: T[], filter: (item: T) => boolean): number {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (filter(items[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```