# how to find the index of array with key value in underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
fnd = _.indexOf([{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}], {id:3});
console.log(fnd); //2
```

How can i find index of with key-value using underscore.js?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [find the array index of an object with a specific key value in underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631127/find-the-array-index-of-an-object-with-a-specific-key-value-in-underscore)

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356642/is-there-an-indexof-in-javascript-to-search-an-array-with-custom-compare-functio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an indexOf in javascript to search an array with custom compare function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356642/is-there-an-indexof-in-javascript-to-search-an-array-with-custom-compare-functio)

Answer (score 0):

```
let index = _.findIndex(fnd, (item) => { 
    return item.id == 2
})
```

For further reading check out the documentation of the method.

http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash indexOf and pluck for this scenario like 
*.indexOf(*.pluck([Array],'KEY'),'VALUE')
Example:

```
var arr = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
_.indexOf(_.pluck(arr,'id'),3);
```

will return 2